# Mysql Date FUnction

Tags: mysql, date

i have this mysql query but it's retuning zero when there are rows with current date in this format '2011-04-07 19:15:11'

```
$query_stat_today = 
  "SELECT C.id
    , C.j_user_id
    , L.j_logged_date
    , COUNT(L.site_id) as total 
  FROM 
    jt_site C
    , jt_access_log L 
  WHERE 
    C.id = L.site_id 
   AND C.j_user_id = ".check_db_query_id($user_id)." 
   AND DATE(L.j_logged_date) = **CURDATE()**";
```

this returns zero

Comment: why the asterisks around `curdate()`? that will generate an error run like that.

Comment: Maybe he was trying to make it **bold**, but that only works in non-code text.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense, because you are matching not against items on the same day, but items in the same second.
if you change

```
AND DATE(L.j_logged_date) = CURDATE()
```

to

```
AND DATE(L.j_logged_date) 
  BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

That way if the logged date is anytime on that day it will match.

Answer (score 0):

`CURDATE()` doesn't return dates in that format. It returns a date value only, ie '2008-06-13'. Also, you're using the `DATE()` function to extract the date value out of `L.j_logged_date`. You shouldn't have any issues there. Your problem lies somewhere else.